# A syntactic annotation tool used to create treebanks

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, tagged-corpus, brat

Can you recommend a good syntactic annotation tool? I want to create a small (phrase structure) treebank.

I know there are some tools used for dependency treebanks, [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) being one of them.
[Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) comes with parse tree viewer, but you cannot create or edit parse trees, as far as I know.

Thank you in advance!

PS: I also tried [WorkFreak](http://wordfreak.sourceforge.net/), which looks fine, but it welcomes me with some runtime exceptions :)